# how to save image in blob field using watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

```
<table>  
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td><img src="xyz.png" width="100" height="100"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*i want to save this xyz.png in blob form into my db, so how can i save image in `blob` form.*

Comment: you need to download it first to local desk and then save it to the database using path location.

Comment: but i want to directly save it in BLOB field of my database.

Comment: This is not really a watir question, other than you are using it to navigate your site and find the source of the header image.  Everything after that is basic Ruby, or a helper gem for dealing with whatever database you are using.

Comment: @Chuck van der Linden , i tried these lines of code.

Comment: img=cell.image.src
image = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(img)).body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img=cell.image.src
image = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(img)).body
```

Comment: this is for save image in blob form.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this quick example I wrote up. Essentially, I just find the image I want using an id and then get it's source. Then, I open a temp file to hold the contents of the image and finally, I open the url of that src and write it to the temp file. The benefit of using tempfile is there is no cleanup.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'open-uri'
require 'tempfile'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto("http://www.reddit.com")
img = browser.image(:id, "header-img").src

tempFile = Tempfile.new('tempImage')
open(img, 'rb') do |image|
  tempFile.write(image.read)
end
tempFile.rewind
puts tempFile.read ###Make your database call here, simply save this tempFile.read as a blob 
tempFile.close
tempFile.unlink # completely deletes the temp file
browser.close
```

For this example, I'm just getting the reddit logo and printing the binary data out to the screen. You never specified which database you're using so I didn't want to assume, but instead of doing 'puts' you'd make your DB call there.

Comment: i have get another solution of it.

Comment: img=cell.image.src
          image = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(img)).body

Comment: if image src generated on run time , then how it will convert?

Comment: sorry for not getting back to you, just saw this now. Thanks for posting your solution below so other people can see it in the future.