# Save images from a website (with watir)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

How can i save website images with **watir**, without reloading them with open-uri or similar?

I: The reason why i can't use

```
      File.open(file_name, 'wb') do |f|
             f.write open(img.src).read
      end # file open
```

is that the images are generated in the current (login-)session and only once, so an "external" 2nd access isn't possible.

II:
`browser.images.save()` - only for ie - isn't helpful either, it opens the save-to dialogue. So its so useless for automation.

Examples: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Save+All+Images+on+a+Webpage

```
 require 'watir'
 browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
 browser.goto 'http://google.com'

 idx = 0
 browser.images.each do |x|
   puts idx
   idx += 1
   location = 'c:\tmp\file-' + idx.to_s + '.jpg'
   x.save(location)
 end
```

github source: http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/Image

```
    # File 'lib/watir-classic/image.rb', line 48

    def save(path)
    @container.goto(src)
     begin
      fill_save_image_dialog(path)
      @container.document.execCommand("SaveAs")
     ensure
      @container.back
     end
    end
```

My best idea atm is to fetch all images by using a proxy. But maybe there is a "watir-way".

Environment:

```
 # ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
 # watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32)
 # watir-classic (3.6.0, 3.5.0, 3.4.0)
 # watir-webdriver (0.6.4, 0.6.2)
```

Edit: i am aware that there are different ways to get images from the website, and without event thinking i could build a list with so much solutions, but its about to solve the problem with ***watir***.

Comment: Why is `browser.image.save(file)` useless? The method opens the save dialogue, inputs the required fields and save the file (ie the dialog is also automated). Or do you mean it is not helpful because it is just for IE and you need to use a different browser?

Comment: In my case it opens the save dialogue and waits. As described in the manual that should only happen if the file exists, but this is not the case (empty directory and random file name)

Comment: That is odd. I have not run into any issues saving an image as a new file.

Comment: i ve added a not working example

Comment: Does the `c:\tmp\` directory exist? Your example only hangs for me if the directory does not exist.

Comment: tried with root directories like c:\ z:\ \ / /cygdrive/z c:/ z:/ and without ... always with the same result... which which version of ruby and watir are you using?

Comment: I tested it on Ruby 1.9.3p194 with watir-classic 3.2 and IE8.

Comment: Does either answer to this question help you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190826/how-to-save-image-in-blob-field-using-watir/16220394#16220394

Comment: What about [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html)?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't open an image once it was showed there is only one Watir way. You can take a screenshot of your image using [Element screenshot extension](https://github.com/ansoni/watir-extensions-element-screenshot). It will be like:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir/extensions/element/screenshot'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "http://your_page.com"
b.element(:id => "your_img").screenshot("Your_img.png")
```

Comment: You might run into an issue related to the window size with this (especially on headless browsers), see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58909678/9138821) for a fix!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider disabling images on the browser being controlled by Watir. Then you can find the URLs in the source and fetch the images for the first time using your code. The net effect should be the same as what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not on windows, so unable to try a 'watir-way', but you could do this simply by calling out to curl or wget:

```
browser.images.each do |img|
  %x| curl #{img.src} -O #{img.src.split('/').last} |
end
```